# Add icon before the preference

Tags: android

I'm doing a android app. I want to add icon before the preference. I want to add icon before the title of the inner preferencescreen, checkboxpreference,... like icon|title
Thank you for your help.
like that picture:

[Top Android App: Quick Settings Dialogue View](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_bbZoRtK3YH8/S0QbkvWxSiI/AAAAAAAAAwI/jU9vRI50ZDw/s320/Top+Android+App+Quick+Settings+Dialogue+View.png)

Comment: I'm sorry, but could you elaborate a little bit more? I'm not 100% on what you asking for

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure if I understood the question correct...The following code works for me, I wish it helps.

```
<Preference
android:key="@string/pref_style_key"
android:icon="@drawable/icon"
android:title="@string/pref_style" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't possible using the out-of-the-box [`PreferenceActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html) (which is what I assume you're using). I think you'll need to code up your own activity for this, and manually get/set the various preferences.

Get/setting the preferences isn't as hard as it might at first sound:

```
// To get a preference (boolean in this example)
PreferenceManager
    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this)
    .getBoolean("someBoolean", false);

// To set that same boolean preference to true
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
Editor editor = prefs.edit();
editor.putBoolean("someBoolean", true);
editor.commit();
```

You will need to figure out when you want to save changed preferences. I'd suggest the `onPause` event of your activity.

Answer (score 0):

It's not supported out of the box, you have to extend the [`Preference`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/Preference.html)¹ class and write your own preference UI type. But you can look at Googles implementation of the Android settings [here](http://google.com/codesearch#ohAXAHj6Njg/src/com/android/settings/IconPreferenceScreen.java&q=IconPreference%20package%3aandroid&type=cs). It's not much work to do so.

¹ *"Represents the basic Preference UI building block displayed by a PreferenceActivity"*.

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest way to achieve what you want is to make the icon a 9-patch icon with the right border as the stretchable area.

Let's say you have an EditTextPreference that you want to add an icon before the title and summary.

You create a MyEditTextPreference class that extends EditTextPreference and override the getView method to add your 9-patch icon as the background resource.

Here is a sample code that works:

```
public class MyEditTextPreference extends EditTextPreference {

    public MyEditTextPreference(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(convertView, parent);
        view.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.my_icon);
        return view;
    }
}
```

Since the icon is a 9-patch, the icon will stretch the transparent part until the right end of the cell, placing the icon on the left side.

This is a very clean solution for your problem.